# Can I split on two characters, running awk only once?

Tags: awk

`ip a` produces bunch IP Addresses and interfaces status

With `awk '/inet / {print $2}'`, I manage to get the IP and the subnet

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip a | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
127.0.0.1/8
10.10.0.1/24
10.10.1.1/24
wolf@linux:~$
```

Then, I pipe it to another awk to remove the CIDR notation.

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip a | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | awk -F / '{print $1}'
127.0.0.1
10.10.0.1
10.10.1.1
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is it possible to do this without piping the awk output to another awk?

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip a | <awk syntax here without additional piping>
127.0.0.1
10.10.0.1
10.10.1.1
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: Non-awk solution is of course to pipe to `cut -f 1 -d /` which could be more easily understood by the next reader of your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this very specific case, have you considered a better use of `ip`? For example:

```
ip -j -p -f inet a | awk -F \" '/local/ {print $4}'
```

This will print `ip address` as a JSON object an search for the `local` key, which happens to store the IP address. Is is even sharper you can use `jq`:

```
ip -j -p -f inet a | jq '.[].addr_info[].local'
```

I recommend this last command as it will not suffer from changes in `ip addr` output. However, if you really like your initial design, I would go with:

```
ip a | awk '/inet / {print substr($2, 1, index($2,"/")-1)}'
```

or

```
ip a | awk '/inet / {split($2, addr, "/"); print addr[1]}'
```

In the first command, we use `index($2, "/")` to find where `/` is in `$2` and then use `substr` to generate the substring. In the seconds one, we split `$2` on `/` and store it on `addr` array.

Answer (score 12):

Actually the field separator you define usung `-F` is a regular expression. Thus the following command should deliver:

```
ip a | awk -F'[ /]+' '/inet / {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 11):

```
ip a | awk '/inet / {FS="/"; $0=$2; print $1; FS=" "}'
```

The first matching record is split into fields according to the default `FS` (space). Then a new `FS` is set. When we substitute `$0=$2`, splitting is done again according to the new `FS`. Now `$1` contains what we want, we print it. Finally we set `FS` for the next matching record.

Comment: Thanks. Both solution works. Which one should I accept?

Comment: @Wolf accept the one you personally feel is best for your need, or you find easiest to understand.  And upvote all answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You could replace the `/` and the following characters with an empty string:

```
ip a | awk '/inet /{ sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2 }'
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solution works. Which one should I accept?

Comment: @Wolf whichever feels the best to you, see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers